# Workflow SharePoint Designer called the service twice

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint workflow from SharePoint designer and I am calling my custom web api, I noticed that the workflow call each api twice. 
I am using SharePoint 2019 on premises not 365.
[image]

And the used headers are Accept & Content-Type and its value is application/json;odata=verbose

Comment: How did you design your workflow? Please provide some screenshots about your actions and "call http web services" action settings to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I tried very simple workflow however please find updated issue

Comment: Is this the complete workflow? Have you called the workflow on both - item creation and updation?

Comment: No on item creation only, the workflow steps are executed once except api call